# How to find the status of microphone access in chrome using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, voice-recognition

I'm working on a voice recognition project and got a requirement to check for the voice recognition access status (Allowed or Blocked) using Jquery in chrome browser, The access rights might be given by the user when he visited my site previously.

I have to perform an action based on that status knowing, if it is blocked?

Comment: No need jquery, you can use [getUserMedia API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/).

Comment: Thanks for your response @Quentin . It actually worked in https

But the problem is: Because of using this voice recognition is not asking for permissions in http.

Is there any other alternative for this problem?

Comment: @AtchyutNagabhairava did you find something ?

Comment: Sorry @djadam, I find no alternative for that problem. We need to have https.

Comment: Np @AtchyutNagabhairava, I found something like `https://github.com/muaz-khan/DetectRTC` with the help of this we can find microphone is enable or not